# Using FreeTTS with Java web start

Tags: jar, java-web-start, freetts

I have a java problem, and need your help to fix it. 
Basically, I have a normal desktop java application, uses an external JAR file. I wanna embed this application within a website, and this page refreshes every 5 seconds?? 
Please if there is anyone can help me, I'll provide him/her more details about it? 
Or could you please forward my issue to a good java programmer. 
BTW, I've tried Java applet and JNLP (Java web start) approaches, unfortunately they don't work.
I've tried this http://freetts.sourceforge.net/demo/JSAPI/WebStartClock/README.html, but the example doesn't work.
The application runs correctly when it doesn't use any external JARs

Answer (score 0):

This is for reolading the whole page...

Put the following in your HTML header:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5">
```

Or, for javascript I would start exploring

```
javascript:history.go(0)
```